# picture in css not showing why?

Tags: html, css, image, path, background-image

ive put a background image in. the header of my website using css and html but the image does not show up. The placement of the image is taken up by the image but the image itself is not appearing on there.

when I inspected the page by chrome inspect tool it says that such a file does not exist but I'm sure i put the correct file path to it I don't know what to do now. Please help.         here is the file orders of which the image is located in[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgwju.png)

the picture should be showing in the empty spot on the left of "David Chu's restaurant"[how the website looks like atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5pCb.png)

HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>David Chu's China Bistro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen&family=Salsa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
            <div class= "navbar-header">
             <a href="index.html" class=" pull-left">
                <div id="logo-img"> <img src=""></div>
            </a>
   
           
   
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h1> David Chu's China Bistro</h1>
        <img alt="Brand">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



    </header>
```

CSS CODE

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Salsa', cursive;
}
#header-nav{
    background-color: #f6b319;
    border-radius:0;
    border: 0;
}
#logo-img {
    background: url('images/resturant-logo_large.png') no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;

}
.navbar-brand{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing `/` at the beginning of the url, like this: `background: url('/images/resturant-logo_large.png') no-repeat;`

Comment: It's `restaurant` in the file name your file explorer screenshot shows, but you wrote `resturant` in your CSS.

Comment: (And relative paths in external CSS resource are relative to the URL of the CSS, not the page you embed it on.)

Answer (score 0):

Things you should fix:

1. There is no ending tag in the image: `<img src="">`
2. No src, and not mentioned any where else in the code. It might as well be deleted

To fix this replace you background with:

```
background-image: url("images/resturant-logo_large.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

If these don't work check if the image exists.
Or remove the no-repeat from the background